# When remapping the yank operator, the named register it lost

Tags: vimscript, register

I'm attemping to call a function when pressing y + motion like this in my vimrc:

```
function! s:MyFunction(reg)
  echo a:reg
endfunction

nnoremap y :<C-U> call <SID>MyFunction(v:register)<CR>y
```

When I type <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, MyFunction echoes `'a'` like expected, but the yanked word is never written to register `"a`, instead it is written to the yank register `"0`.

Why and how to fix this so my mapping honors the specified named register?

Comment: Well, your function needs to do something with the given register. From your example, it is not clear, why you think anything should appear in register a

Comment: My thinking is that Vim replaces the 'y' in "ayw with my mapping. So as I specfied "a in front, VIm should complete the command as so. I do realize it doesn't seem to work this way...

Comment: I think, what is happening is, that by the time the command `y` is executed, the value of `v:register` is actually lost. That's why you see the value echo'ed, but after that command is finished, Vim resets v:register, so the `y` does not see the specified register anymore

Comment: Makes sence. If I make a second call to MyFunction like: nnoremap y :<C-U> call <SID>MyFunction(v:register)<CR>:<C-U> call <SID>MyFunction(v:register)<CR>y. I only get an echo of the default register..

Answer (score 3):

It seem that the v:register *is* lost after calling MyFunction. After a bit of reading I found `map-expression` that can be used to solve the issue like this.

```
function! s:MyFunction(reg)
  echo a:reg
  return '"'.a:reg.'y'
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> y <SID>MyFunction(v:register)
```